# Warning when adding `group_by %>% summarise` to list(): number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: r, dplyr

My code:

```
library(dplyr)
L <- list()
L["Gear"] <- group_by(mtcars, gear) %>% summarise(n = n())
geargroup <- group_by(mtcars, gear) %>% summarise(n = n())
```

The second line produces this message:

```
Warning message:
In L["Gear"] <- group_by(mtcars, gear) %>% summarise(n = n()) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

`L["Gear"]` contains only the `gear` column, but `geargroup` has both the `gear` and `n` columns.

How do I make `L["Gear"]` have both `gear` and `n` columns?

Comment: Use a double bracket. `L[["Gear"]]` I think will solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Username is right, the double bracket solves the problem.

```
library(dplyr)
L <- list()
L[["Gear"]] <- group_by(mtcars, gear) %>% summarise(n = n())
```

Output:

```
> L
$`Gear`
# A tibble: 3 x 2
   gear     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     3    15
2     4    12
3     5     5
```

See also [the section on lists in Hadley Wickham's R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/vectors.html#lists)